# php arrays - detect modified row and edit

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my HTML page, I have a form where users can add new rows using a button. 
A "row" is composed of an `input` (`interventions`) and a `select` (`interventions_status`) and you can have "unlimited" rows.

When the form is submitted, it builds arrays (`interventions`, `interventions_status`), that I store in my database using `serialize`.

The input `interventions` is build (value) like this : `WHAT_DOES_THE_USER_DO||LAST_EDITED_BY||LAST_EDITED_TIMESTAMP`.
Buuut, that I want is that the `LAST_EDITED_BY` and `LAST_EDITED_TIMESTAMP` to be updated by my script. In fact, "`||`" is a 
separator and only `WHAT_DOES_THE_USER_DO` is displayed to users.

In order to update the value of my `interventions` input, I have to detect if a row has been edited. And if it has been edited, to update
the `LAST_EDITED_BY` and `LAST_EDITED_TIMESTAMP`. But, a row can only be edited depending on the select, `interventions_status` which
contains only a number (0 = ok, 1 = no, 3 = in progress).

`interventions_status` and `interventions` are on "the same row", so if I edit `interventions_status[3]` for row 3, it is "linked" with `interventions[3]`.
So, if third select edited, I would like to edit the third input also.

I've tried using `array_diff` comparing the saved (db) version and the posted version of `interventions_status` (don't forget that datas are serialized) then trying to "select" the `interventions` row that match the edited `intervention_status`. But doesn't working...

Maybe you have a better solution?

Hope it's clear...

Table :

```
+----+------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| id | interventions    | interventions_status | engine_id |
+----+------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| 1  | SERIALIZED_DATAS | SERIALIZED_DATAS     | 298E70D   |
+----+------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| 2  | SERIALIZED_DATAS | SERIALIZED_DATAS     | 290A98T   |
+----+------------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: can u post the description of your mysql table

Comment: Done in original post

Comment: ah so you mean you wanted an activity log

Comment: @NewbeeDev that's about it, but an activity log for a row (a row is composed of interventions & interventions_status).

Comment: could you provide your table structures here.

Comment: @NewbeeDev If interventions_status concerning a "row" has been edited, I would like to edit the corresponding interventions (they are both array as you can have 10 interventions) - example : I edit row 4 by changing the value of interventions_status which is also the FOURTH ROW in my array interventions. If edited, apply edit to interventions.

Comment: you should show us some code. For what I can understand you are updating all the rows of the table in the db each time you update one select. You shoul update only the right row passing the id (and not the array index)

Comment: you should be giving more details. Its quite confusing about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you question, you have a table with rows in your html code.

When you edit a row's `interventions_status` you should be sending `id` of that row too i.e. `id` which is stored in your table for that row.

Now check if previous/already stored  `interventions_status` is different from current one. If yes then, `update the row`.

I hope this is the solution you are looking for !

Comment: @Jugrati that's exactly what I need :)

Comment: @jugrati That's what is on my mind, but I need some code.... I can't apply this on my application :( :(

Comment: can you send `row id` with form data when submitted ?

Comment: When I speak about a "row", it's a row of my array (index) not the row of my database (sorry)